# Unable to drop or truncate sql server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory

We are using azure data flows and we are trying to load the data in one particular table in sql server. however our data flow keeps running for hours for smaller set of data.
when we tried to truncate or drop the table, our request times out.

how can we force drop and recreate the table.

What I checked
We don't have any foreign constraints that may avoid the drop

**Getting this error when i tried to truncate**

> Failed to execute query. Error: A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

I also ran this query and found this

Query -

```
 SELECT  session_id
     ,blocking_session_id
     ,wait_time
     ,wait_type
     ,last_wait_type
     ,wait_resource
     ,transaction_isolation_level
     ,lock_timeout
    FROM sys.dm_exec_requests
    WHERE blocking_session_id <> 0
```

[image]

Is this causing the issue

How can I fix this issue

i found this after running

exec sp_who 88

[image]

What can i do on it

Comment: so find out more about blocking session 88 , run `exec sp_who 88` , seems like this is the session that is blocking , find out more about blocking stuff , if you are allowed to add a proc to the database , go get and install `sp_whoisactive` which gives you more information

Comment: i found a select command after running exec sp_who 88. what can i do to fix it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find out more about blocking session 88 , run `exec sp_who 88` , seems like this is the session that is blocking , find out more about blocking stuff , if you are allowed to add a proc to the database , go get and install `sp_whoisactive` which gives you more information

then you can run : `dbcc inputnuffer(88)` to find out which main proc or process is executing that select query.
if this is safe to kill that process, you can kill that session by

kill 88

before killing that session make sure that session id is still running the same process